# How to change body style on vaadin

Tags: sass, vaadin

How to change body tag  style on `vaadin`? I am using `.v-sa` but it does not work and `.v-generated-body` neither.

Comment: Paste your full code. Including html

Comment: the usual steps to take here are in your browsers devtools: make sure your code changes are in the actual sent out css file (pick it from the header or the network tab and scroll to the end or about where you expect your code to be).  next pick the element in devtools and look at the applied styles to see if something "more accurate" overrides your style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just assume you want to change the background color. If not, please specify what properties of the `body` element you are trying to style.

Most probably the theme defines a background color for the `.v-app` element, which is on top of the body element (and 100% high), so you never see the background you define for the `body`.

So you either need to set the `.v-app` background to transparent and set your preferred background to `body`, or just set your preferred background directly to `.v-app`.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to style <body> tag but i can't style it using scss. Can i have any chance to change <body> tag ? and not .v-app it is inside of <body> tag

Comment: Use Csslayout for your main application as it allows to supply inline styles.

Comment: @BatgerelEnkhbat You can style the body with SCSS as well. Just note that you might need to use the `.v-generated-body` class to have enough specificity over the Valo theme styles. And as I said in my answer, you need to set `.v-app` background to transparent also in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Popup windows appear as sibling v-app elements (with added v-overlay-container) under the body.  So if you want to add a classname at runtime that applies to the main ui along with all popup windows, you DO NEED to access the body element directly.  We have had a specific use case that required this.

```
body v-generated-body
- v-app 
- v-app v-overlay-container
- v-app v-overlay-container
```

Here is the code we used:

```
String additionalClassName = "my-selector";
com.vaadin.ui.JavaScript.eval("document.body.class +=  ' " + additionalClassName + "';");
```

There are other (better) ways to get the Javascript executed, such as adding an extension to your container, setting the classname in the shared state, and updating the element from the client side.  This approach would prevent the Vaadin runtime from wiping out your changes when it resyncs the client.  I don't think the body tag is subject to that situation though, so this eval hack might serve your purposes in production.